# validating if sort options work on protractor

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I am new to protractor and I have clicked on my webpage to sort items by prices low to high. How do I check that the first item has price less than the second and so forth?

Any kind of guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Shark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$$('cellTargetSelector').getText().then(valueArray => {
            valueArray = sort(valueArray);
            sortBtn.click();
            $$('cellTargetSelector').getText().then(valueArrayAfterSort => {
                for(let i=0; i < valueArrayAfterSort.length; i++) {
                    expect(valueArrayAfterSort[i]).toEqual(valueArray[i]);
                }
            });
        });
```

Where `sort(arr)` func returns sorted `arr`

Comment: i want after sort $9.9 to be validated as less than $10.99. toEqual still relevant?